# Direct link to an image inside a gallery

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink, gallery

I have to edit a wordpress site right now. One of the task is to give thumbnails a direct link to point the image directly in the gallery instead of the gallery page.

I can change the link in the thumbnails but I cannot find out what is the link which goes inside the gallery directly to a specific image. And of course keep the paging capabilities after that.

Comment: which gallery are you using? if you want to refer to a special picture you can go to media and on the right botom side of your picture you can find the link.

Comment: @CD Rolling, Yes, I have already try this and the image will have been shown up, but looses the paging capabilities. After that it will a simple image and not a member of a gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the gallery being used, in most cases you link to the gallery index.

Comment: Thank you CHEWX! Im not yet familiar, could you please write an examle url for this?

Comment: Do you have a link, like I said, it would depend on the gallery plugin being used, it's a custom solution for each.